# EFCore SQLite connection string with relative path in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, asp.net-web-api, ef-core-2.0

I have just added SQLite to my asp.net webApi project, and am having trouble working out how get the path to the App_Data folder to pass to `DbContextOptionsBuilderUseSqlite`

I have the following in the `web.config` I have a link to an external a config file with the conenction string...

```
<connectionStrings configSource="config\connectionStrings.config"/>
```

and in there I have...

```
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDatastore"
             connectionString="DataSource=./App_Data/test.sqlite" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

And in my `DbContext.OnConfiguring` I Have....

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
          if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
          {
            string path = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatastore"].ConnectionString;
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(path);
          }
    }
```

The path is correctly retrieved (I can see I get the path as configured on `connectionStrings.config`

so `./App_Data/test.sqlite` is passed to `optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(path)`.

However, I get the following error...

```
SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.
```

If I use just `connectionString="DataSource=test.sqlite" />` then it seems to magically find the file in the App_Data folder, when I ran on my dev machine in debug, but I had problems on another machine (release build). I assume it is the path, though all I get back is 'unable to open database file'.

I also tried..

```
 connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|test.sqlite" />
```

This gives me a `Illegal characters in path` error.

The following does work (full path)

```
 connectionString="d:\0\test.sqlite" />
```

But I want to be able to use relative paths, eg maybe even `.\datastore\test.sqlite`.

Does any one have any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to fix up the relative paths at runtime:

```
var builder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);               
builder.DataSource = Path.GetFullPath(
    Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") as string
            ?? AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        builder.DataSource);
connectionString = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

*Note: This solution was tested for .Net Core 5, and one can presume it will work on 2.x, 3.x, 5*

If you want to use a diferent project than the one provided when you started, you have to specify the correct path ("Data Source = ..\\MyApplication.DAL\\sqliteDatabase.db") in the appsettings.json.

In this presented case, you don't even need to write the method OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in the ApplicationDbContext.cs.

You have a full setup bellow (Startup & appsettings.json).

My project structure:

```
 -> MyApplication (solution)
      -> MyApplication.UI (initial project of the solution)
      -> MyApplication.BL (project)
      -> MyApplication.DAL (project)
```

Inside Startup.cs

```cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           //... other services 
           
           services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>
                (x => x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqliteConnection"))); 
           
           //.... other services and logic
        }
```

In appsettings.json :

```js
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqliteConnection": "Data Source = ..\\MyApplication.DAL\\sqliteDatabase.db"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Works perfectly for me.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var dataSource = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "siteDB.db");
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlite($"Data Source={dataSource};");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me on linux, .net core 5.

```cs
var builder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder("Data Source=MyDatabase.db");
builder.DataSource = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, builder.DataSource);

services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(o => o.UseSqlite(builder.ToString());
```

Assumes database is in the bin directory, e.g. `MyProject/bin/Debug/MyDatabase.db` or `MyProject/bin/Release/MyDatabase.db`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a .Net Core backend developer who use sqlite, make sure to use below code example. Otherwise **SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'** error will come.

Startup.cs

```
var baseDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
string dbPathSystemLog = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "CAMSCoreSystemLog.db");
```

SystemLogDBContext.cs

```
public class SystemLogDBContext : DbContext
{
    public SystemLogDBContext(DbContextOptions<SystemLogDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

This line will create the Db if not exist

```
Database.EnsureCreated();
```

I was struggling two days. This will help someone.

Comment: This is certainly not a generic solution. Who says that the database file is always in that location?

Comment: You have to create that there.. Other locations lead to permission issues.. The user accessing the API endpoint is not a user in the server or pc.